# What is the difference between Docker Hub and Quay.io?

Tags: docker, continuous-integration

I need to compare Docker Hub to Quay.io. The Slant community recommends Quay.io for most people. Quay.io is ranked 4th while Docker Hub Registry is ranked 8th. Which one is the better option for me?

Comment: Where do you look? Here? https://www.slant.co/topics/2436/~docker-image-private-registries

Comment: Only a programmer could answer this question though.

Answer (score 9):

They are just different Container registry platforms with the main difference in the pricing model they offer.

- Quay.io [plan](https://quay.io/plans/) is more expensive but provides you features like easier Continuous Integration, Robot accounts, Teams, SSL Encryption, Logging & Auditing...
- Docker Hub has a free [plan](https://www.docker.com/pricing) where you have unlimited public repositories, but with rate-limit of pulling only 100 private repositories per 6 hours. You need to pay when you want to disable rate-limit, vulnerability scans, larger teams, or more parallel builds.

*EDIT: Updating Docker's plan info as of 12/31/2020*

Comment: one tiny difference is that you need to install docker.io to pull images or there will be an error like `toomanyrequests: You have reached your pull rate limit`. This is not friendly. But quay.io is good.

Comment: I edited answer with rate-limit mention @MichaelWang